# base64 encode clob to blob

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to base64 encode a blob to clob. I've done some searching and the same function seems to be suggested:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION base64encode(p_blob IN BLOB)
  RETURN CLOB
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- File Name    : https://oracle-base.com/dba/miscellaneous/base64encode.sql
-- Author       : Tim Hall
-- Description  : Encodes a BLOB into a Base64 CLOB.
-- Last Modified: 09/11/2011
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IS
  l_clob CLOB;
  l_step PLS_INTEGER := 12000; -- make sure you set a multiple of 3 not higher than 24573
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 0 .. TRUNC((DBMS_LOB.getlength(p_blob) - 1 )/l_step) LOOP
    l_clob := l_clob || UTL_RAW.cast_to_varchar2(UTL_ENCODE.base64_encode(DBMS_LOB.substr(p_blob, l_step, i * l_step + 1)));
  END LOOP;
  RETURN l_clob;
END;
/
```

My question is, what determines the maximum size of `l_step`? I've tried setting it to 24573 and I receive the following error:

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: raw variable length too long, ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_ENCODE"
```

I tried setting it lower to 23808 and that seemed to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) "The ratio of output bytes to input bytes is 4:3 (33% overhead)"

24573 is 75% of 32767, which is the size limit for a VARCHAR2.

It isn't mentioned in the documentation, but observing the behaviour of Oracle 19c, it appears the UTL_ENCODE package line-wraps the Base64 string to a max line length of 64 characters (presumably so that the encoded string can be used directly with MIME).

On a Windows platform, this means that you will have 2 characters (CRLF) inserted for every 64 characters of standard Base64.

Rounding 32767 down to a multiple of 4, we start with 32764 as the maximum output size.
Dividing by 66 tells us we have 497 lines of text, of which the last doesn't have a doesn't have a CRLF added - i.e. we need to allow for 992 extra characters inserted. Now our usable length is down to 31772, and 75% of that gives us our actual input limit of 23829, confirmed on Oracle 19c as producing a Base64 output string of length 32764.

Comment: Fully right, obviously function `UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2` returns a `VARCHAR2` data type which is limited by 32767 bytes. Since `UTL_ENCODE.base64_encode` returns pure ASCII the limit is equal to 32767 characters. Multi-Byte character conversion should not apply.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
FUNCTION base64encode(p_blob IN BLOB) RETURN CLOB
    IS
      l_clob CLOB;
      l_step PLS_INTEGER := 1998;
    BEGIN
      FOR i IN 0 .. TRUNC((DBMS_LOB.getlength(p_blob) - 1 )/l_step) LOOP
        l_clob := l_clob || UTL_RAW.cast_to_varchar2(UTL_ENCODE.base64_encode(DBMS_LOB.substr(p_blob, l_step, i * l_step + 1)));
      END LOOP;
      RETURN l_clob;
    END base64encode;
```

Comment: How does this answer my question?

Comment: I'm telling you what works for me based on experience.  I ran into similar issues you did years ago when I first implemented it, trying larger step values.